# Adding edge features in heterographs using PyGeometric

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

For some reason I'm not being able to assign features to edges using [`HeteroData`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.data.HeteroData.html#torch_geometric.data.HeteroData) from PyGeometric package. The version installed are Python 3.11.5, PyTorch 2.0.1+cu117 and TorchGeometric 2.3.1 running over ArchLinux in a virtual environment.

Given the following code snippet

```py
import torch
from torch_geometric.data import HeteroData

data = HeteroData()

# Params
num_papers, num_paper_features = 5, 7
num_authors, num_author_features = 4, 10
num_edges = torch.randint(5, num_papers*num_authors, [1]).item()
author_writes_paper_num_features = 4

# Adding features to nodes
data['paper'].x = torch.randn(num_papers, num_paper_features)
data['author'].x = torch.randn(num_authors, num_author_features)

# Creating some random edges
author_edge_index = torch.randint(0, num_authors, [num_edges])
paper_edge_index = torch.randint(0, num_papers, [num_edges])
edge_index = torch.stack((author_edge_index, paper_edge_index))
data['author', 'writes', 'paper'].edge_index = edge_index

data = data.coalesce()

# Adding features to edges
data['author', 'writes', 'paper'].x = torch.randn(author_writes_paper_num_features, data.num_edges)

# Also tried using the transpose edge feature matrix 
# data['author', 'writes', 'paper'].x = torch.randn(data.num_edges, author_writes_paper_num_features)
```

But, while I can correctly fetch node features

```
data.num_node_features
# {'paper': 7, 'author': 10}

data.node_stores
# [{'x': tensor([[...]])},
#  {'x': tensor([[...]])}]

data.node_attrs()
# ['x']
```

The same does not happens with edge features

```
data.num_edge_features
# {('author', 'writes', 'paper'): 0}
```

Is *ZERO*. Even with a `x` entry in edge_stores.

```
data.edge_stores
#[{'edge_index': tensor([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
#         [0, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2]]), 'x': tensor([[...]])}]
```

We can see that no feature attribute `x` is associated with edges

```py
data.edge_attrs()
# ['edge_index']
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Edges should use `edge_attr` Python attribute instead `x`. That is, you should instead use

```py
# Adding features to edges
data['author', 'writes', 'paper'].edge_attr = torch.randn(author_writes_paper_num_features, data.num_edges)
```